# javafx.scene.Node ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, javafx

I've got an old automation project on Java 1.8, but I have some issues with launching it. It took some time to resolve all dependency issues but now there is an exception that I don't know how to solve.

I have installed jdk and jre 1.8 and I've double checked that my project is using those tools, but when I try to run the tests I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/Node
at com.fpt.cme.art.main.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Node
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to find out the reason. I think there are some problems with JavaFX, but as far as I know, JavaFX is a part of Java 1.8 so there is no need to install it separately.

I'm using a Windows system and Oracle Java 1.8. Main goal is to run automation tests, but for now I can't even start debugging cause I have internal jvm error

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got a solution!

1. Download javafx distributive from https://openjfx.io/
2. Add --module-path "path to javafx lib folder" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml to VM arguments in IDE

Comment: But that means that you run it on Java 9 or newer (after the introduction of the module system)

Comment: I really have no idea how it started to work, cause the only Java I have in my system is oracle 1.8